# Why: Incorrect range width, was 14 but should be 16 when every row in my array is 16 items?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to update a google sheet using data from a second google sheet.

A "subject sheet" contains a list of every single student taking a subject, a "teacher sheet" contains a list of students of that subject in a particular teacher's class.

A Head of Subject will add columns to the subject sheet to record values of test scores.

Once those headings have been added my script needs to update the teacher sheet with the same headings.

Additionally, any student rows in the teacher sheet but not existing in the subject sheet will be added to the end of subject sheet. A student is identified by a value in a column called "UPN".

Before I run the comparison I make sure both sheets have the same number of columns like this:

```
//ensure every row in teacherArray has (at least) the same number of cols as subjectArray
  if (teacherArray[0].length < subjectArray[0].length)
  {
   for (row = 0 ; row < teacherArray.length; row ++)
   {
     for (col = teacherArray[0].length; col < subjectArray[0].length; col ++)
       {
         teacherArray[row].push("");
         dataChanged = true;
       }
   }
  }
```

I then do various comparisons and updates...

If there are any rows in teacherArray that do not exist in subjectArray I push them onto the end of subjectArray.

```
if (!foundUPN)
{
  dataChanged = true;
  subjectArray.push(teacherArray[tar]);


}
```

Finally, I try to write back the data to my sheet:

```
          if (newSubjectData)
          {
            sheet.getActiveRange();
            sheet.clear();
            for (var row = 0; row < newSubjectData.length; row ++)
            {
              Logger.log("row: " + row + " width: " + newSubjectData[0].length);
            }
            //Logger.log("About to try to write updated newsubjectdata: rows: " + newSubjectData.length + " cols: " +newSubjectData[0].length + "sheet rows: " + sheet.getMaxRows() + " cols: " + sheet.getMaxColumns());
            sheet.getRange(1,1,newSubjectData.length, newSubjectData[0].length).setFormulas(newSubjectData).setNumberFormat('@STRING@');

          }
```

I've cleared the contents of the sheet before proceeding, I've set the range to be the size of the array. I've confirmed that the array is perfectly rectangular by iterating through each row and logging the width, (every row contains here 16 items when run on these particular spreadsheets) and yet my spreadsheet will not update. It keeps reporting "Exception: Incorrect range width, was 14 but should be 16"

14 is the width of the original teacher sheet/array before additional headings have been put on, but this data is not what is being used, it's the updated version. Really confused and perplexed, what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Spotted my mistakes.
Firstly, my attempt to show the width of the array in every row was not showing the actual value.

```
    for (var row = 0; row < newSubjectData.length; row ++)
            {
              Logger.log("row: " + row + " width: " + newSubjectData[0].length);
            }
```

newSubjectData[0].length should be newSubjectData[row].length

```
            for (var row = 0; row < newSubjectData.length; row ++)
            {
              Logger.log("row: " + row + " width: " + newSubjectData[row].length);
            }
```

Fixing that showed me that actually, each row was not the same width. My original attempt to ensure the two arrays are the same width did not work, so I have moved the resize operation to just before I push the new row to the main subject array.

```
if (!foundUPN)
{
  dataChanged = true;
  //still not getting the correct col widths
  if (teacherArray[tar].length < subjectArray[0].length)
  {
    for (cols = teacherArray[tar].length; cols < subjectArray[0].length; cols ++)
    {
      teacherArray[tar].push("");
    }
  }
  subjectArray.push(teacherArray[tar]);
  Logger.log("UPN not found pushing row width: " + teacherArray[tar].length);

}
```